# Azure Active Directory two factor authentication is broken

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am unable to log in to my database in the Storage Explorer because I enabled two-factor authentication with Azure Active Directory (worst mistake ever). Now, the login in Storage Explorer just hangs for a long time, then eventually fails. Same in Visual Studio cloud explorer.

What's worse, I cannot disable two-factor authentication because if I click "Active Directory" in the new portal it shows the cloud with the rain/tear drop, meaning something is wrong with it and no settings can be changed. I've tried everything, even looking at the old portal and deleting the multi-factor auth resource from my account, which supposedly would have disabled multi-factor, but it still is failing and is requiring multi-factor authentication.

Help please!

Comment: Can you describe the steps you followed to enable MFA?

Comment: You should *probably* file a support ticket. I use MFA and it works fine.

Comment: I actually can't exactly describe it as the process is so un-necessarily complex that I can hardly remember (who comes up with this stuff?). But I'm starting to think what's really going on is that I started the Azure Active Directory Premium trial and that somehow is ruining things. I need to either disable the conditional access rule I created (at the subscription level), or cancel the trial. Unfortunately, disabling the conditional access rule is not possible because that panel is not loading in the portal! Anyone know how to do that with powershell?

Comment: I did open a support ticket but they are not going to address it until business hours (Monday....). Meanwhile, I'm locked out of my database.